# Ubuntu volume lower than on Windows

Tags: ubuntu, audio

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 on my Dell XPS 9370, I have noticed that the volume in Windows is much more than in Ubuntu. I have checked alsamixer and both master and PCM are set to 100%.

I know I can increase the volume beyond 100% from the settings but thats really irritating and I want 100% to be the real 100%.